# Настройка роутера Cisco Packet Tracer

Tags: маршрутизация, cisco-packet-tracer

Возникла проблема при настройке роутера в Packet Tracer.
Сеть состоит из двух роутеров, коммутатора и двух компов.
Надо настроить маршрутизацию (статика), по заданым параметрам:

```
pc1: ip-192.168.1.10 / 24, default gateway: 192.168.1.1;
pc2: ip-192.168.3.10 / 24, default gateway: 192.168.3.1;
R1:  f 0/0 - 192.168.1.1 / 24, f 0/1 - 192.168.1.2;
R1:  f 0/0 - 192.168.3.1 / 24, f 0/1 - 192.168.2.2.
```

Не пинговался PC1 с PC2, понял, что R1 и R2 не в одной подсети. Поменял 
`К1: f 0/1 - 192.168.1.2` на `f 0/1 - 192.168.2.1.` Проблема осталась.
Поскажите что делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, что для начала стоит правильно задать все подсети! 
Если я правильно понял вы хотите реализовать след.схему: *PC1 - L3(1) - L2 - L3(2) - PC2* 
(L3 - роутер;L2-коммутатор) 
L3(1) имеет LAN 192.168.1.10/24 клиентская подсеть 
L3(1) имеет WAN 192.168.1.2 
L3(2) имеет LAN 192.168.3.1/24 клиентская подсеть 
L3(2) имеет WAN 192.168.2.1 
Итого, это как-то "не очень" развернутая подсеть `192.168.1.1/16`: в вашей маленькой сети 65534 рабочих хоста. Крутовато для реальных 4 машин) 
Но даже если вы на широкую руку захотите реализовать сеть `/16`, то лучше уж так:
192.168.1.1/30 (подсеть PC1-L3(1)) 
192.168.1.5/30 (L3(1)-L3(2)) 
192.168.1.9/30 (подсеть PC2-L3(2)) 
Дальше прописывайте, как вы и хотели на L3(1) маршрут к L3(2). 
`Router(config)#ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.6` прописываете на 192.168.1.5. 
И наоборот.  
Пока писал, ради интереса проверил в CPT:

```
Router#sh ip int br  
Router#sh ip int brief   
Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method    Status                Protocol

FastEthernet0/0        192.168.1.9     YES manual up                    up

FastEthernet0/1        192.168.1.5     YES manual up                    up

Vlan1                  unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down

Router#ping 192.168.1.2
Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 192.168.1.2, timeout is 2 seconds:
!!!!!
Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 0/0/1 ms
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться